# How do I make my document use the Times font, both for the text and the math?

Tags: fonts, times

I know that I can put `\usepackage{times}` in the preamble in order to use the Times font instead of Computer Modern for my document.  But this only affects the text; the math is still typeset using Computer Modern.  How can I make Latex use Times also for the math?

Comment: The font Times itself doesn't come with any support for maths; the answers below are free maths fonts that go well with Times.

Comment: There several great answeers below, but just as a side-remark: [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/) is an excellent place to look in situations like this.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Probably the most common solution at present using free fonts is `mathptmx`

```
\usepackage{mathptmx}
```

This package supersedes `times` and `mathptm`.

The commercial `mathtime` is available in a 'lite' version in a free (cost) package, but you need to pay for the full version. See http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html

As noted in the [answer by mafp](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95348), the newer `newtx` bundle is now available and addresses issues present in `mathptmx`.

Comment: Most up to date? Isn't txfontsb considerably newer than mathptmx?

Comment: I can't see any mention of 'Times' in the txfontsb documentation, nor of the range of math support. (The focus seems to be on Greek.)

Comment: It's an extension of the txfonts package, which provides Times in both text and math mode. The documentation may focus on Greek, most likely because that's what's different compared to txfonts. But load the package and you'll see.

Answer (score 32):

In the mean time, two new option for Times have emerges. The [`newtx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/newtx) package provides both text and math versions for Times via

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

The [TeX Gyre](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre/) project supplies [TeX Gyre Termes](http://ctan.org/pkg/tex-gyre) for text to be used with

```
\usepackage{tgtermes}
```

and a math version [TeX Gyre Termes Math](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tex-gyre-math) that currently only comes in Open Type Format, and can be used with

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO,vargreek-shape=TeX]{TG Termes Math}
```

in LuaTeX or XeTeX, and with

```
\starttypescript [math][times,termes][all]
    \definefontsynonym[MathRoman][file:texgyretermes-math-1010.otf][features=math\mathsizesuffix]
\stoptypescript
```

in ConTeXt.

Comment: This caused an error "! LaTeX Error: Command \openbox already defined. Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual."

Comment: @Jeff What exactly, i.e., do you have an MWE?

Answer (score 9):

If you don't mind using a Times-like font, a different engine, and the not yet officially released TeXLive-2010, then you can try XITS font with LuaLaTeX (my preference) or XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{XITS} % you can use any other Times font if you wish
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\begin{document}
Some text and \(\sqrt{x+y}=z\) equation
\end{document}
```

Comment: Include the [STEP fonts](//ctan.org/pkg/step) as well here...

Answer (score 9):

With current TeXLive 2012 and `lualatex` or `xelatex`

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

\begin{document}
Some text and \(\sqrt{x+y}=z\) equation
\end{document}
```

[image]

see package documentation of `fontspec` for optional arguments to the font setting.

Answer (score 4):

I’ve  been using the **txfontsb** package for Times, though generally I avoid Times. (After reading countless student papers in Times, it grates on me.)

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
\usepackage[bigsym]{mathptm}
```

in your preamble.  This makes LaTeX use the Times and Symbol fonts for math, except for large symbols (summation, integration, etc.) which look funny in the Postscript Symbol font.

Comment: According to http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/psnfss/psnfss2e.pdf mathptm is "obsolete", you should use mathptmx instead.