# AIP Template: greeks letters not working

Tags: templates, greek

I am trying to use the American Institute of Physics latex template but for some reason some greek letters and other math symbols are not working. Maybe it's my pc. So below is a `aipproc` document class file for you to check where `pi`, `infinity` and `Omega` are not rendered properly.

```
\documentclass[
    ,final            % use final for the camera ready runs
%%  ,draft            % use draft while you are working on the paper
%%  ,numberedheadings % uncomment this option for numbered sections
%%  ,                 % add further options here if necessary
  ]
  {aipproc}

\usepackage{times,mathptm}
\usepackage{amsfonts} %mathbb
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\layoutstyle{8x11single}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% FRONTMATTER
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage{amsfonts, amsthm, latexsym}
%\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath, graphicx}
\begin{document}

\title{why are greeks and other symbols failing?}

\classification{02.60.-x,02.70.Bf}
\keywords      {}

% \author{<author1>}{
%   address={<author1 address>}
% }

\author{me}{
%  address={<common address for author2 and author3>}
}

\author{him}{
  address={Department of Applied Mathematics}
 % ,altaddress={<author1 address>} % additional visiting address
}


\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
Pi: $\pi$, Infinity: $\infty$, Omega: $\Omega$

\end{document}
```

Comment: take a look at [How do I make my document use the Times font, both for the text and the math?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/669/579)

Comment: @barbarabeeton this is hardly helpful

Answer (score 4):

the answer cited in my comment explains why the `times` and `mathptmx` font packages are obsolete and should not be used.  they have been superseded by `mathptmx`.

the `aipproc` class defaults to `mathptmx`.  by overriding that, you have caused the
math fonts to stop working properly.

remove the line

```
\usepackage{times,mathptm}
```

then you will get this result:

[image: output of corrected example code]

`aipproc.cls` and associated package files are not included in tex live, so to perform
this test, i had to go to the aip web site to download them.  it is possible that you
are using an old version of the package.  you should check for this possibility.

Comment: I also downloaded the files from http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/proceeding/aipcp/info/authors. I have removed the line but my problem is not gone. What could be wrong. I use linux