# Need Help in formatting my Book - Chapter headings - Headers

Tags: spacing, formatting, header-footer, chapters

I am a Chemical Engineering graduate and I am helping my mentor in typesetting his book. He has given me the text and equations in MS Word and I have to convert the same in `LaTeX.`

I used Adobe InDesign for typesetting, however i was not pleased with its formatting of mathematical equation. Hence i starter learning LaTex a month ago.

I am facing some formatting issues on my chapter headings and headers and footers. I tried using `quotchap`,`fncychap` and `fancyhdr` packages, still i am not satisfied with the results. Hence i need to know how to format my Chapter and header-footer manually.

I tried to explain my problem as detail as possible for the readers to understand.

My requirements are,

1. I need the chapter number to be aligned right to say "CHAPTER-ONE" instead of "Chapter 1" and the Chapter heading to be aligned center and need 2 horizontal lines,first 0.35mm,second 0.2mmm across the page. As Shown below,[image: Chapter Model] Instead i get the formatting shown below.[image: Chapter I get]
2. I need to get the header to be in a specific format as shown below.[image: Header model]
   Also, I need a line of 0.25mm across the textwidth. But, When i use `fancyhdr` package, I get this[image: Header I get]
3. I DON'T want a footer at all, because i need space for footnotes.
4. I am using the `geometry` package for customizing my paper size and margins. I need to know whether i can include bleed. The image given below can give you an idea. This is the Adobe InDesign Document properties.[image: Page dimensions].

My code for preamble and first section is given below, Please tell me what i did wrong.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{quotchap}
%\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage[paperheight=24.5cm,paperwidth=18cm, left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,bindingoffset=7mm,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
%\title{Heat and Mass Transfer}
%\author{Prabhu}
%\date{}
\begin{document}
%\maketitle
\chapter[]{Basics Concepts}
\section{INTRODUCTION}
Heat transfer is a discipline of thermal engineering that concerns the generation, use, conversion, and exchange of thermal energy and heat between physical systems. In engineering practice, an understanding of the modes of heat transfer is becoming increasingly important since heat transfer plays a crucial role in the design of vehicles, power plants, refrigerators, electronic devices, buildings, and bridges, among other things. The science of thermodynamics deals with the amount of heat transfer as a system undergoes a process from one equilibrium state to another, and makes no reference to how long the process will take. But in engineering, mainly interested in the rate of heat transfer, which is the topic of the science of heat transfer.
\medskip\fussy
```

I will answer any clarifications needed regarding my problem if asked.

I sincerely thank each and every individual in advance for trying to help me with my problems. I expect a positive reply from the forum as soon as possible.

- P.Prabhu (bond.483348@gmail.com)

Comment: It is usually better to ask one question at a time.  In this case, questions 2 and 3 are related, but none of the other ones are.  You can link the questions so that people don't propose incompatible answers.  (And for those of us who don't know, can you explain what 'bleed' is? Or provide a link to where it is explained?)

Comment: @jon , Thanks for the insight.  I will separate the questions. "Bleed" is a term used in printing , It is the area that gets trimmed after the final print is done. It helps the author as well as the printer to have some breathing space in case the printer goes off mark. It helps with books with large number of pages. U can look in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleed_(printing) for more info.

Comment: jon , If possible, Could u please help me with questions 2 and 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to go about implementing issues #1, #2, and #3.  (I leave aside #4; but this is an issue that can be dealt with *much* later on.)

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{book}
% If we store the book title in a macro, we can use it in many places
\newcommand{\thebooktitle}{Heat and Mass Transfer}

% Fonts, encodings, languages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% Page dimensions
\usepackage[
  paperheight=24.5cm, paperwidth=18cm,
  left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm,
  bindingoffset=7mm,
  includehead,includefoot
  ]{geometry}

% Provides dummy text for testing purposes
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Header Style:
% booktitle | chapter-number.page-number | chapter title
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\lhead{\thebooktitle}
\chead{\thechapter.\thepage}
\rhead{\leftmark}
% Make sure footer is empty
\lfoot{}\cfoot{}\rfoot{}

% Chapter Style:
\usepackage{titlesec}% titlesec has \titleformat, \titlerule, \filleft, \filcenter
\usepackage{fmtcount}% fmtcount has \NUMBERstring
\def\firstchaprule{\titlerule[0.35mm]}
\def\secondchaprule{\titlerule[0.2mm]}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\Large}
  {\filleft\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \NUMBERstring{chapter}}
  {2ex}
  {\vspace{1ex}%
    \filcenter}
  [\vspace{1ex}%
  \firstchaprule
  \vspace{1pt}%
  \secondchaprule
  ]

\title{\thebooktitle}
\author{Prabhu}
\date{}
\begin{document}
% We want an 'empty' (or plain?) pagestyle for the front matter
\pagestyle{empty}
% \pagestyle{plain}
\maketitle
\chapter{Basics Concepts}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\section{INTRODUCTION}

\lipsum[1-20]% generates dummy text for testing purposes

\end{document}
```

Comment: jon, I really thank u for answering. when i ran the code which u gave, It worked beautifully. However, when tried copying the Header and footer section onto my original code.. Somehow, it doesn't work. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: What's your original code?  (Is it what is posted in your question?) And what is the error?  It sometimes helps to organize your preamble in a "rational/logical" manner as this can help find out where conflicts are arising.  I usually break it into related chunks of material: page dimensions, fonts/encodings, language/bibliography, page layout, chapter and sectional styles, etc.

Comment: jon, please ignore the previous comment, i looked into it and found that i did not add `\pagestyle` inside the document. It works beautifully now. Thank you so much.

Comment: Also, is it possible to change my font settings to times new roman instead of LaTeX's original font?

Comment: jon, Please Help.. I am getting an error message as `! LaTeX Error: File `fmtcount.sty' not found.` I tried to check whether it is available in CTAN website and it is. I downloaded the .zip file but i don't know how to install it. Please help.

Comment: jon, I got it.. just had to extract the .zip file in my sub directory. Thank you for all your help. God bless u.

Comment: Glad it's working.  Regarding using Times New Roman, if you are using `pdflatex` (as this answer is), look at [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/669/8528); basically, you want to use either `\usepackage{mathptmx}`, `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`, or ` \usepackage{tgtermes}`.

Comment: Thanks jon, I used the `\usepackage{mathptmx}` for Times New Roman. I still have some queries regarding creating macro environments which i can use it inside the code. I will ask it in detail in another question.