# How to use the same font from another pdf document

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I saw one pdf document in [this](http://cs.wellesley.edu/~cs230/spring07/lectures/lec12_pqueues_sets_bags/lec12_pqueues_sets_bags.pdf) link, I like the font style and wish to use it in my latex document.

From the pdf property dialog, I can see below information,I guess the fonts maybe Roman, but how can I use it in my latex file? for example, use the font in this test document.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\begin{document}
Hello world!
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Which font? Maybe helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/669/how-do-i-make-my-document-use-the-times-font-both-for-the-text-and-the-math

Comment: This is Comic Sans, [perhaps the world's most overused and hated font](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Comic%20Sans). If you want to use it you have to download and install the font file, which can be found around the internet. Afterwards you can use in in your own documents, see for example the [LaTeX Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts#Using_alternative_fonts).

Comment: I do not intend to insult anyone but the request of using ComicSans seems like a late April's fool or a typographer's version of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0. 

I randomly picked up these: http://www.comicsanscriminal.com,  http://knowyourmeme.com/photos/127274-comic-sans, and https://designforhackers.com/blog/comic-sans-hate/. I would be happy if someone could offer a quote by Spiekermann on this matter. But I doubt he actual cares for such nonsense.