# Additional space cells in tables with equations

Tags: tables, equations

I try with some recommendations to add vertical space for cells with equations, and I couldn't achieve it.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\usepackage[math]{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

\usepackage{color,colortbl,hhline}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}    
\begin{table}[htpb]
    \centering
    \caption{Solución de la ecuación }
        \begin{tabular}{|p{1cm}|p{12cm}|}
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray} \thead{Caso} & \thead{Solución} \\
        \hline
        $\zeta = 1$ & $u(t) = [u(0) + (\dot u(0) + u(0) \omega_n )t]e^{-\omega_n t}$\\\hline
        $\zeta > 1$ & $u(t) = \dfrac{e^{-\omega_n\zeta}}{2\omega_n\sqrt{\zeta^2-1}}\left\lbrace\left[\omega_n(\zeta+\sqrt{\zeta^2-1})u(0)+\dot u(0)\right]e^{\omega_n\sqrt{\zeta^2-1}}-\big[\omega_n(\zeta - \sqrt{\zeta^2-1})u(0)+\dot u(0)\big]e^{-\omega_n\sqrt{\zeta^2-1}}\right\rbrace$ \\\hline
        $\zeta < 1$ & $u(t) = e^{-\omega_n\zeta t}\left[u(0)\cos{\omega_Dt} + \left(\dfrac{\dot u(0) + \omega_n\zeta u(0)}{\omega_D}\right)\right]$ \\\hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Update**

Maybe I can't anchieve the solution because of conflicts between some packages. This is my preamble, and the Typeset Engine is `pdfLaTeX`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setdefaultlanguage[babelshorthands]{spanish}
%\usepackage[Ligatures=TeX]{fontspec}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noshorthands]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44694/fontenc-vs-inputenc
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/669/how-do-i-make-my-document-use-the-times-font-both-for-the-text-and-the-math
%\fontspec{Times New Roman}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{ifthen}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Arial}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

%\usepackage[htt]{hyphenat}
%
%\usepackage{pdflscape}

%\usepackage[title]{appendix}

\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibltarea6.bib}

%\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[math]{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
basicstyle = \ttfamily,
keywordstyle= \color{blue}\textbf,
commentstyle= \color{gray},
stringstyle= \color{green!70!black},
stringstyle= \color{red},
columns= fullflexible,
numbers= left,
numberstyle= \scriptsize\sffamily\color{gray},
xleftmargin= 0.07\textwidth,
xrightmargin= 0.05\textwidth,
showstringspaces = false,
}

%\usepackage{inconsolata}

%\newcommand{\Cpp}{C\texttt{++}}
%\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Código}
%\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{Índice de códigos}

%\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepgflibrary{arrows.meta}
%\tikzset{%
%  newTip/.tip={Bar[sep=-1.45pt, width=10pt] Circle[sep=-1.25pt,width=2.5pt,length=2.5pt]}
%  }
%\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
%
%\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepgflibrary{arrows.meta,shapes.arrows}
%\tikzset{%
%  newTip/.tip={Bar[sep=-1.45pt, width=10pt] Circle[sep=-1.25pt,width=2.5pt,length=2.5pt]}
%  }
%\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc}

%\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{25}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode = symbol}

%\usepackage{pgfplots}

%\newcounter{myrow}

%\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{threeparttable}

%\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\bfseries\normalsize}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\bfseries\normalsize}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\bfseries\normalsize}

\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}

%\usepackage{layout}

\usepackage{color,colortbl,hhline}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}

%\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm, top=3cm, right=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\setlength{\hoffset}{.46cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{13.08pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-7mm}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{0cm}
\setlength{\headheight}{8mm}
\setlength{\headsep}{4.6mm}
\setlength{\textheight}{24cm}
\setlength{\footskip}{8mm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{15.5cm}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
 \lhead{\footnotesize{Pontificia Universidad Católica del Perú}\\ \footnotesize{Escuela de Posgrado - Ingeniería Civil}}%Significa que est
 \chead{}%Vac
 \rhead{\footnotesize{Dinámica de Estructuras\\ Tarea 1}}
 \lfoot{\footnotesize{}}%Pie izquierdo
 \cfoot{\thepage}
 \rfoot{\footnotesize{Fernández Yopla, Isai}}

 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}%Falta investigar
 \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\usepackage[pass]{geometry}%pass tells output driver which paper size use.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

equation in the second row/column is far to long. you need to split it in two lines. for example with use the `aligned` environment from the package `mathtools`. for more vertical space you should used `S` column specifier from `cellspace`. for example for the second column: `S{p{12cm}}`:

**edit:**

- in cases, when the `siunitx` package is used, the `S` specifier from the `cellspace` package had to be replaced by `C`, i.e. `C{p(12cm)}`
- in mwe below i consider only for table relevant packages
- off-topic: since you also use the `geometry` package, you can define page layout with it and remove all other low level page layout definitions in your preamble

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44694/fontenc-vs-inputenc
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noshorthands]{babel}
\usepackage{mathptmx}%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/669/how-do-i-make-my-document-use-the-times-font-both-for-the-text-and-the-math

\usepackage{makecell,hhline}        % <---
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{cellspace}              % <---
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

\usepackage{mathtools}              % it load "amsmath" too
\usepackage{siunitx}                % <--- used it, the "S" from the "cellspace# package
                                    %  had to be replaced with "C"
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}          % <---
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\usepackage{geometry}               % for simple determination of page layout.
                                    % see its documentation!

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htpb]
    \centering
\caption{Solución de la ecuación }
    \begin{tabular}{|p{1cm}|C{p{12cm}}|}
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        \thead{Caso} & \thead{Solución}             \\
        \hline
        $\zeta = 1$  & $u(t) = \bigl[u(0) + \bigl(\dot{u}(0) + u(0) \omega_n\bigr) t\bigr] e^{-\omega_n t}$     \\ \hline
        $\zeta > 1$ & $\begin{multlined}
            u(t) = \dfrac{e^{-\omega_n\zeta}}{2\omega_n\sqrt{\zeta^2-1}}
            \biggl\{\Bigl[\omega_n\Bigl(\zeta+\sqrt{\zeta^2-1}\Bigr)u(0)+\dot{u}(0)\Bigr] e^{\omega_n\sqrt{\zeta^2-1}} -  \\
            \Bigl[\omega_n\Bigl(\zeta - \sqrt{\zeta^2-1}\Bigr)u(0)+\dot{u}(0)\Bigr] e^{-\omega_n\sqrt{\zeta^2-1}}
            \biggr\}
                        \end{multlined}$                \\  \hline
        $\zeta < 1$ & $u(t) = e^{-\omega_n\zeta t}
        \biggl[u(0)\cos{\omega_Dt} + 
            \biggl(\dfrac{\dot{u}(0) + \omega_n\zeta u(0)}{\omega_D}\biggr)
        \biggr]$                                        \\  \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think that I have some packages in conflict, because I don't have the results, and `S` doesn't work: _"./T1Dyn18.Isai.tex:299: Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (p{12cm}): `c' used."_

Comment: I have been working with `pdfLaTeX`.

Comment: ups, at editing table code i overwrite last three lines of mwe code. sorry. now corrected. i consider all packages in mwe in your question and compile mwe with pdfLaTeX. apparently you tested table code in document with different preamble. solution, as it is now, works (tested again).

Comment: I have updated the question with my preamble, I would like you to help me to fix this.

Comment: @Isai, as i suspect, your real preamble is different. problem cause use of the `siunitx` package. when you use it, than `S` from `cellspace` had to be replaced by `C`. i will edit my answer asap.

Comment: Thanks for your intention, I think that the software has problems. I have Texpad.

Comment: It is done with updated packages.

Answer (score 3):

As @Zarko has already pointed out in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448802/5001), the main problem is that one of the main equations is far too long to fit in a single row. Use an `aligned` environment to introduce a suitably chosen line break.

Once you've line-broken the long equation, there's no need to use `p` column types; instead, just use the basic `l` column type for both columns.

In order to declutter the tabular material some more, I would remove the repetitive `u(t) =` parts from the cells and, instead, stick that information into the table's caption.

I would also like to suggest that you give the table a much more open "look", mainly by getting rid of all vertical and horizontal black lines -- they're simply not needed. I'd also load the `booktabs` package and use its `\addlinespace` macro to further increase whitespace between rows.

In addition, I would replace all `\left` and `\right` directives with explicit sizing instructions.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} % new
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for "\addlinespace" macro
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'aligned' environment

\begin{document}    
\begin{table}[htpb]
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\centering
\caption{Solución de la ecuación por $u(t)$}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\rowcolor{Gray} \textbf{Caso} & \textbf{Solución } \\
\addlinespace
$\zeta = 1$ & 
$\displaystyle
  \bigl[u(0) + (\dot u(0) + u(0) \omega_n )t\bigr]
         e^{-\omega_n t}
$\\ \addlinespace
$\zeta > 1$ & 
$\begin{aligned}[t]
\frac{e^{-\omega_n\zeta}}{2\omega_n\sqrt{\zeta^2-1}}\Bigl\lbrace
  &\bigr[\omega_n(\zeta+\sqrt{\zeta^2-1})u(0)+\dot u(0)\bigr] 
    e^{\omega_n\sqrt{\zeta^2-1}}\\
-&\bigl[\omega_n(\zeta - \sqrt{\zeta^2-1})u(0)+\dot u(0)\bigr]
    e^{-\omega_n\sqrt{\zeta^2-1}}\,
\Bigr\rbrace
\end{aligned}$ \\ \addlinespace
$\zeta < 1$ & 
$\displaystyle 
e^{-\omega_n\zeta t}\bigl[u(0)\cos{\omega_Dt} 
+ \bigl(\dot u(0) + \omega_n\zeta u(0)\bigr)\big/\omega_D
\bigr]$ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But I have to work with `siunitx`, and this is the problem: `.
! File ended while scanning use of \__siunitx_tmp:w`

Comment: @Isai - Please see the revised code I just posted. It no longer uses the machinery of the `cellspace` and `makespace` packages and hence, by construction, doesn't interfere with anything the `siunitx` package does.

Comment: Thanks for your intention, I think that the software has problems because I have the same problem with `siunitx`, but when I don't use it, everything is right. I have Texpad software.

Comment: Done! I had to update the packages.