# How can I get even font heaviness on my equations?

Tags: fonts, equations

I'm having trouble getting my equations to have a homogenous look with text when using the times font package. The Userpackages I'm using are:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{amssymb}    
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{asymptote}  
\usepackage{changepage} 
\usepackage{color}     
\usepackage{enumitem}   
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   
\usepackage{framed}     
\usepackage{geometry}   
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{helvet}     
\usepackage{marginnote} 
\usepackage{times}   
\usepackage{multicol}   
\usepackage{multirow}   
\usepackage{pgffor}    
\usepackage{setspace}   
\usepackage{tikz}       
\usepackage{totalcount} 
\usepackage{accents}    
\newcounter{QuestionCounter}
\setcounter{QuestionCounter}{1}
```

The actual code for the equation is `\item\mrks{1} If $(x+iy)^{2n}=a+ib$ where $x,y,a,b,n$ $\in{\mathbb{Z}}$ find the value of $(y-ix)^{4n}$ in terms of $a$ and $b$.`
Which produces the following, where the equations look like they're in italics, how can I get rid of that while still having Times New Roman font?
[image]

Comment: Right now you are using Times font for text and Computer Modern for math. You can use a Times-like font also for math (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95348/82917) but math will still be in "italics", as that is common typography.

Comment: use `\usepackage{newtxttext,newtxmath}` not `times` (which is really obsolete and deprecated, it has a companion `mathptmx` package to use a similar font in math but the newtx set is a far more modern and complete setup

Comment: Note that there is a small mistake in the previous comment: the text package is called `newtxtext` (3 t's, not 4).