How to set document font to Times new roman and font size to 13
I want to know how to set font of a document to Times new roman and font size to 13. I tried using the mathptmx package but I can't set font size to 13. Is there any way to have both Times new roman and font size 13. Please help me out on this.

Please always focus on one question. In your case it would be recommended to show, how you already have changed to Times New Roman, but failed to change the font size. BTW: Font size 13 of what? 13pt? 13bp? 13mm? 13cm? Please always be as exact as possible. BTW: I would not recommend mathptmx any longer, because at least in math mode it is a mixture of different fonts. IMHO, there are better alternatives. See, e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95348/277964
